# Script Null into raw trasaction bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, script, bitcoin-core-development

I'm developing a parser for bitcoin core and into the alpha test of the parser,I noticed than the script bitcoin core are null and the hash raw transaction exist.

An example: for this transaction the script into exploring for blockchains
[Transactions example into blockexplorer](https://blockexplorer.com/tx/c78854360663aa585b0400df7297afc458521bf858e6c93b34d4ca696ae30f29)
[Transactions example into blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/it/btc/tx/c78854360663aa585b0400df7297afc458521bf858e6c93b34d4ca696ae30f29)

I have two questions now:

1. *This null script event what is it due to? Is there any phenomenon I am not aware of?*
2. *Do these explorer sites to determine the starting and destination wallet execute the script*?

Thanks for your help.

Sorry for my terrible English but I'm learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This null script event what is it due to? Is there any phenomenon I am not aware of?

There is no script needed to spend the transaction vout referenced in the input because it was not locked with a key. For example, the txid of the first transaction referenced is `c3d8d15a3ca1b50fc2519cbcb79f1db3b6be164c176c7ad51c7a5ec2e97ffa7b` with output index `204`. Below is how the that transaction output was locked.

```
{
    "value": 0.00000000,
    "n": 204,
    "scriptPubKey": {
        "asm": "7daba6288bcf43c2f7f555ec58f965eaac89b14bc4c4fc920a2a58163aa11e0e",
        "hex": "207daba6288bcf43c2f7f555ec58f965eaac89b14bc4c4fc920a2a58163aa11e0e",
        "type": "nonstandard"
    }
}
```

The locking script basically pushes 32 bytes of data onto the stack (`7daba6288bcf43c2f7f555ec58f965eaac89b14bc4c4fc920a2a58163aa11e0e`) with no verification opcodes at the end of it. That means, it can be spent with an empty signature. This types of transactions were generally done if you wanted to store hash of some data on the bitcoin blockchain. But that can now be achieved with a OP_RETURN opcode which prevents UTXO bloat. All but the last transaction that has been referenced are coinbase transactions which is paying out fractions of the newly generated bitcoins to the participating miners of the pool. It is possible that the pool manager wanted to encode and store a particular data onto the bitcoin blockchain.

Comment: an questions stupid, this transaction whit script null wase spent by everyone?! in what sense if you wanted to save the hash?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo (1) Not spent by everyone. All the transactions that were referenced were not locked with any script, so it was an any one can spend kinda output and hence did not require any signature to spend. (2) Say the pool operator wanted to save the data of affiliated miners that were not rewarded in that transactions. However, he doesn't want to make that information public. So he would just group all those non-rewarded miners addresses together and compute SHA256 of that and use that as a locking script.

Comment: what is the sense of the pool store the data affiliated miners?

Comment: I just gave a random example to cite what could be done. There is no way of knowing what data was encoded as hashes are irreversible.

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo if you think my answer effectively solves your doubt, you could click the correct mark next to the answer so others know this is an accepted answer.